# Find a particular cell from a PrimeFaces datatable in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am kind of new to Primeface and JQuery. I have a datatable and I would like to access a particular cell of that datatable in jquery. Below is what I am trying to do--

My Datatable code:

```
<p:dataTable id="employeeDataTable" var="employee" value="#{userPreferenceBean.employeeDataModel}"
            paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{userPreferenceBean.selectedEmployeeList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

            <f:facet name="header">
                List of Employees
            </f:facet>

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />

            <p:column headerText="Primary Employee" style="width:2%">
                <p:commandButton value="Me" update=":#{p:component('primaryEmployeeDetails')}" id="ajax"
                    actionListener="#{userPreferenceBean.saveEmployee}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary">
                    <f:param name="employeeName" value="#{employee.name}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:48%">
                    #{employee.name}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Department" style="width:48%">
                    #{employee.department}
            </p:column>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Save Preferences" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                    update=":#{p:component('selectedEmployeeDetails')}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Now I would like to access the commandbutton from a particular cell (say for example nth row and 2nd column) from JQuery. This is what I am doing now -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ui-priority-primary").click(function() {
            alert('test')
            var row = 'employeeDataTable:' + rowIndex + ':ajax';
            $(row).each(function() {
                alert('test again')
            });
        });
});
```

Now the alert with 'test' is working, but alert with 'test again' is not working. It means I am able to get the click event from the command button. But looks to me I am not able to get the particular cell from a datatable. Can you please help me to understand what mistake I am doing here? Thanks.

Regards,
Sudipta Deb

[image: Generated HTML]

Comment: Is there any `UINamingContainer` like a `h:form` surrounding the datatable? Check the generated HTML and post the generated ID of the table.

Comment: This is what is getting generated: id="j_idt5:employeeDataTable"

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you would like to get the cell in the row with `rowIndex` and in the column with `columnIndex`. So what you would do to get that cell via jQuery is the following:

```
$(document.getElementById("myForm:employeeDataTable"))
    .find("tbody:first").children("tr:nth-of-type(" + rowIndex + ") td:nth-of-type(" + columnIndex + ")")
```

As you need the absolute ID it would be better to give the parent a proper name or you can use `document.getElementById("#{p:component('employeeDataTable')}")` instead, so primefaces does the ID-lookup for you.
I used `document.getElementById` instead of the jQuery ID-selector `#`, because then you would have to escape every `:`.

---

So for your given function use the following:

```
var row = $(document.getElementById("myForm:employeeDataTable")).find("tbody:first").children("tr:nth-of-type(" + rowIndex + ")");
row.each(function() {
  alert('test again')
});
```

to alert `test again` for each row of the `dataTable`.

Comment: Thanks @user1983983. Somehow alert with ('test again') is not working. I have added the screenshot of generated HTML Page. I have given an id to form also i.e. myForm

Comment: @SudiptaDeb I updated my answer, I guess I checked the generated HTML structure with a different primefaces version. I added the use of `find` before `children` to get the first `tbody` element inside of the div with that ID.